# Как в scss/sass импортировать не весь файл, а один стиль запретить?

Tags: css, bootstrap, sass, scss

В bootstrap есть стиль для ссылок и кнопок, выделение точками вокруг элемента + цвет + подчеркивание на событии :focus, выглядит это так:

```
a {
  color: $link-color;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: $link-hover-color;
    text-decoration: $link-hover-decoration;
  }

  &:focus {
    @include tab-focus;
  }
```

и

```
@mixin tab-focus() {
  // Default
  outline: thin dotted;
  // WebKit
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Если outline: none; еще можно сделать после импорта .scss в своем файле, но что делать с цветом и подчеркиванием, если нужно, чтобы цвет и подчеркивание сохранялись те, что и были, то есть если была синяя ссылка с подчеркиванием, то при клике она должна оставаться такой же. Если же прописать конкретный цвет и подчеркивание, то для другой, например красной ссылки без подчеркивания, она будет изменяться, а не оставаться собой.

То есть, нужно вообще не импортировать эти стили или как то удалить их после импорта. Ведь редактировать исходники .scss неправильно? Тогда как удалить все :focus ы?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае необходимо писать свой миксин наподобие 
`@mixin tab-focus()`, только с указанием параметров, которые вы сможете указывать для конкретных классов.
получается

```
@mixin tab-focus($outline_dotted, $outline_offset, $outline_size ) {
  outline: $outline_dotted;
  // WebKit
  outline: $outline_size ;
  outline-offset: $outline_offset
}

a{
&:focus {
    @include tab-focus('none', '-2px', '5px');
  }
}
```

Comment: Как это поможет сохранить стили, если их может быть допустим 50 шт.: разные кнопки, ссылки, и везде из bootstrap наложится свои точки на фокус, цвет и подчеркивание. Чтобы убрать потом их, писать еще 50 стилей с :focus, чтобы оставить их первоначальный вид? Проще из bootstrap убрать это добавление и при выходе новой версии сделать тоже самое, раз нет нормального выхода, отмена/удаление/исключение стиля после импортирования...

Comment: Бутстрап на то и написан, что бы делать одинаковые стили для элементов по всему сайту. Если вас не устраивает стиль предложенный бутстрапом, то в любом случае тогда путь один - писать свои стили для нужных вам элементов, или же переопределять стили которые уже предложены разработчиком. Удалять каждый раз как выходит новая версия фреймворка вообще абсурд.